# Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I Am Doing this from AppDelegate.
I have two storyBoards, **main** storyBoard and **secondStoryboard**. When i set ***main interface*** to **secondStoryboard** from ***deployment info of app target,*** and run the project the following code works as charm.

**But**  When i set ***main interface*** to **main** story board from ***deployment info of app target,*** and run the project it is Throwing the warning and the presentViewcontroller method is not working.

:( pls help ! Thanks in advance.

```
var storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "secondStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
var congratulationScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("s_id_SecondVC") as! SecondVC
var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: congratulationScreen)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: are you use this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method??

Comment: kind of , actually i am using nstimer on app delegate to trigger this method !

Answer (score 0):

check this call after delay with dispatch Queue

```
   let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(0.1*Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            var storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "secondStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
            var congratulationScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("s_id_SecondVC") as! SecondVC
            var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: congratulationScreen)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
```

Comment: I think this replaces the root view controller of window, my problem is on presenting the viewController over rootviewController @Gaurav